# Magento Go C# requesting API fails to initialize

Tags: c#, magento

I am trying to connect to Magento API using C#. I am using Magento Go service and from what I've read I am able to use their API - I hope I am not wrong here. So here is what I did:

I added a Service Reference to `http://mydomain.gostorego.com/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1`, and just adding a service worked fine. Now I created a `test` class with `GetStuff()` method, which looks like this:

```
using ww.Feeds.MagnetoGoService;

public static string GetStuff()
{
     MagnetoGoService.Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerPortTypeClient s = new MagnetoGoService.Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerPortTypeClient();
     var login = s.login("username here", "key here");
     return login.ToString();

}
```

When I run the program I get an error in first line saying:
`Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'MagnetoGoService.Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerPortType' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.`

Any ideas what this may be? Do I have to set something up in my Magento Go settings? Or maybe using Magento Go is not allowing API access?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Where you got user name and key? From appropriate api user? Does it have enough rights?

Comment: Yep. Another thing I just figured out - I can get it to work using Web References, but Microsoft does not recommend using them anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone ever has problems with this, my solution was this:

I used the reference in one project, but I actually called the class and had main program in another project. You need your Service reference to be in each project wherever you're using it. That fixed it! Alternatively you can create a new BasicHttpBinding() and putt all the options from app.config/web.config into that binder, then you don't need to reference to Service everywhere. I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Forget SOAP with c# you will pull your hair out.  Download Charls Cook's xml-rpc api libary for c# and use the xml-rpc method.  You won't get all the snazzy intellisense  but at least it will work.  There's also c# solution from ez.newsletter they released with Cook's library demonstrating how to use 80% of the magento api calls.

Cook's library xml-rpc.net
http://www.xml-rpc.net/

ez.newsletter solution
http://code.google.com/p/csharlibformagexmlrpcapi/

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work via SOPA using Web Reference. I was hoping to make it work with Service Reference, but something is screwed up there. It's my first ever API integration and I am already starting to go mad :)